# (Opencv) Isolate object to better detect it

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

i'm trying to detect some trees in a picture and I tryed different ways. At the end I chose a BOW+SVM approach, by creating a dictionary and then applying it to the .train(...) of my SVM. I found out that this isn't enough for what I have to do, since classification gives me wrong result. So I tried a treshold on my test images by applying a clustering for colors, but of course, grass is detected too, so it's not very helpful. My training images (for dictionary and SVM training) are all .png images (so tress without background) and that's why I'm trying to segment my test images (which instead have background) to isolate trees. I have tried some basic OpenCV segmentation tecniques but they don't seem to work. One method I tried is that to cluster the image by colors, keeping only the green part: then I tried to eliminate grass by deleting all the rows that have more than 70% of the pixels colored, but this strategy is ok for only some test images that have a big part of grass. Is there any other strategy I can follow? Thank you

Comment: Can you share image samples you wanna try to detect trees? Morphological functions may not be enough to detect your trees, you may need to use advanced training techniques. But again it depends on the requirements.

Comment: Sure, these are some test images: https://imgur.com/0kNLROB https://imgur.com/FKb2d0s https://imgur.com/UGmyDQ0
i rather not use depp learning tecniques for this purpose, but let me know what you think

Comment: This is not a simple task and I dont think segmentation or other morphological techniques will be helpful. Because samples including different type of trees different environment etc. So my suggestion is only training trees with a proper dataset will be helpful in your case

Comment: Thank you, so I give up on this strategy..